# CloudFront serving outdated content from Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm storing a static web site on Amazon S3 and delivering by Cloudfront. I pushed changes to S3 but Cloudfront is still showing the old files. I made an invalidation in Cloudfront with this path /* which is supposed to clear tho whole cache but it  still shows the old staff. I'm wondering how to solve this.

Comment: I found in another stack overflow question that you need to hard reload your webpage by pressing CTRL+F5 or  clear your computer cache by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+DELETE.